# How to copy 2 directories in linux overwritting only older files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian

I wrote a such script in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMP="/home/pi/project/temp/"
TARGET="/home/pi/project/deployed/"
cp -au $TEMP/. $TARGET
```

I figured out how to copy files but it takes so long time :(
I my temp directory I have changed only one file and

```
cp -au $TEMP/. $TARGET
```

is coping all files and overwriting them!

Answer (score 3):

[rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) would be a better option.

`rsync -avzpr "$TEMP" "$TARGET"`

Comment: I just have checked that I need to "cp -au $TEMP/. $TARGET" dose rsync do the same? I need to merge $TEMP content into $TARGET content

Comment: Thank you ;) but it is still very slow :( I got also lots of logs like this: remote: node_modules/yargs/locales/th.json        
remote: node_modules/yargs/locales/tr.json